# How should i fix the Warning C6308 '

Tags: c

im getting an warning message which says.  Warning  C6308   'realloc' might return null pointer: assigning null pointer to '*destination', which is passed as an argument to 'realloc', will cause the original memory block to be leaked.  and im wondering if some of you could help me to fix this problem.

My code:

```
void dstring_truncate(DString* destination, unsigned int truncatedLength)
{
    assert(destination != NULL);
    assert(*destination != NULL);
    assert(truncatedLength >= 0);
    
    *destination = realloc(*destination, truncatedLength + 1);  // +1 för nollterminatorn
    if (*destination == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation faild\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `DString` such that you can dereference it like that? If you're trying to change a pointer to a C string (`char*`) then you'll need to pass in a *pointer to that pointer*, in other words, `char**`. If `DString` is already intrinsically a pointer of some kind, it'd help if you explained.

Comment: Ok here is a small part from my assignment. The file dstring.h contains the interface part of DString which is an ADT for dynamically allocated text strings. It contains five function declarations. With these functions one can initialize/allocate, concatenate (merge), truncate (shorten), write to file and free memory for a dynamic string. The file also contains comments that describe what the functions do.

Comment: Just assign the result from `realloc` to a temporary variable. If the reallocation succeeds, assign the temporary variable to your destination variable.

Comment: epidemy? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74803021/realloc-does-not-work-when-shrinking-block-only-when-expanding/74803654?noredirect=1#comment132055162_74803654